Image not displaying on interactive plotly graph in dash
So I want to build a dash app where the user can interact with an image and return different things depending on where they click.
I followed this tutorial here: How to obtain Click Event Coordinate Data on Plotly Dash Graph in Python? to set up the interactive graph using clickData, and it works perfectly. The problem is, when I try to add an image to overlay on top of the figure, it does not display.
This is my code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import math, json
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.graph_objects as go


GS = 300
fig = go.Figure()

fig = fig.add_traces(
    px.scatter(
        x=np.repeat(np.linspace(0, 1, GS), GS), y=np.tile(np.linspace(0, 1, GS), GS)
    ).update_traces(marker_color="rgba(0,0,0,0)").data)

fig = fig.add_layout_image(
        dict(
            source="https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/python-logo.png",
            xref="x",
            yref="y",
            x=0,
            y=0,
            sizex=2,
            sizey=2,
            sizing="stretch",
            opacity=1,
            layer="above")
)

# Build App
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = dash.html.Div(
    [dash.dcc.Graph(id="graph", figure=fig), dash.html.Div(id="where")]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("where", "children"),
    Input("graph", "clickData"),
)
def click(clickData):
    if not clickData:
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
    return json.dumps({k: clickData["points"][0][k] for k in ["x", "y"]})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)

Currently, it only displays a blank figure, although it does return the points correctly when clicked. However, the image does not overlay on top of the graph.
